# Get environment identifier in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

I'm working with an environment, and I need the identifier of this environment. The function `environmentName()` doesn't work. It returns `""`, so how can I get the identifier of a environment?

Example:

```
a #this is a environment
<environment: 0xbc6d2bc>
environmentName(a)
""
```

I need this id "0xbc6d2bc".

Note: I didn't create the environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There might be a function that does this for you, but you can always just capture the output and extract that number yourself:

```
sub('<environment: (.*)>', '\\1', capture.output(a))
```

**edit:** there is a function in `data.table` that does this for you:

```
library(data.table)

address(a)
```